# Should i show all the selected items in a data table in a popup when editing items?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing

Currently I have a large list of items that can be up to 1000. I am allowing users to select from this list of items and remove them from the group they are assigned to. I have the popup created, but when deciding the text for the popup I realized that using the words "these devices" might make the user expect to see a list of selected devices as a preview. Should I show the list of selected devices in the popup, even if the number can be in the hundreds? (I'd page to use pagination and show like 5 at a time as a default) If not, should I keep this text even though users may expect to see which devices "these devices" is referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a scroll section with a search bar. It's better than using pagination.
This image is just for reference, you can adjust them however your like.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would change the wording a bit: add a counter and remove "these":

> **Remove devices from the Group**
>
> Are you sure you want to remove **50** devices from the group?